# Ubuntu 18.04 - GUI does not start

Tags: boot, 18.04, partial-upgrade

I have some trouble while starting Ubuntu 18.04; while booting, it seems that some kind of [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRCd4.png) occurs (sorry for the bad quality of the photos, I had no other option than using my phone).
The message disappears anyway after a few seconds, and I get redirected to the user login page, which does not appear as a GUI interface as usual (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsjTA.jpg)). From there, I was able to login to my user and use the default Ubuntu terminal, from which I was able to successfully update using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and also reboot the system. Anyway nothing has changed.
I think that this could be due to the updates I installed this morning; Ubuntu wasn't able to install all updates so I had to do a partial upgrade via terminal:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Any help with restarting Ubuntu the normal way will be appreciated!

---

EDIT: by typing

```
sudo apt install xinit
```

and using startx command I was able to enter GUI but it did not show any folder or sidebar.

---

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuKLo.png) from `apt-get check`

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNPj7.png) from `lspci -v | grep -A8 'VGA compatible controller'`

Comment: 1. Please post the output of `sudo dpkg --audit` 2. Which display driver are you using.

Comment: 1. No output is given (it just skips to a new prompt) 2. I can't really tell just from the terminal, but I have always used the default open-source Xorg driver and not the Nvidia one (and I never had any problem)

Comment: Try `apt-get check` and see if it finds packages/dependencies that need to be fixed.
Then see with `lspci -v | grep -A8 'VGA compatible controller'`
if the graphic card has a driver loaded to drive it.

Comment: Thank you, I posted the resulting code above. (I don't really know where to look at, I'm sorry!)